# Как использовать класс одного проекта в другом проекте в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Т.е существует два каталога со своими пакетами>классами, как мне добавить в проект 1 - классы из проекта 2

С использованием import

Comment: Copy->Paste?...

Comment: Действительно. В чём у вас проблема? Вы же можете зайти в папку проекта и скопировать исходники и вставить в папку исходников второго?

Comment: Это не подходит. Нужно подключение через import ...
Но не работает, хоть два каталога находятся в общей папке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Импортировать можно только скомпилированные классы. В проекте исходники не скомпилированы, засим их нельзя просто так в одном проекте добавить из другого.

Добавлять надо скомпилированные файлы. Например в виде архива `jar`. Для этого из первого проекта сделайте этот `jar` и подключите его как библиотеку во втором проекте